# Deserialize a JObject to a list of .NET objects

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

The task I have is to parse JSON into objects which can then create a form. This form can have sub-forms within it and it is this step I am having difficulty with.
Consider this JObject which is a representation of the sub-form and, because the main form has already been deserialized, is now passed as a JObject:

```
  {
  "3705": {
    "type": "radioGroup",
    "label": "Loft Insulation Applicable",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "2",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null,
    "child": [
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "No",
        "order": "3"
      },
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "Yes",
        "order": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3708": {
    "type": "input",
    "label": "Existing Depth (mm)",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "5",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null
  },
  "3709": {
    "type": "input",
    "label": "Required Depth (mm)",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "6",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null
  },
  "3715": {
    "type": "radioGroup",
    "label": "Total Pipework Meterage",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "16",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null,
    "child": [
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "15 mm",
        "order": "17"
      },
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "22 mm",
        "order": "18"
      },
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "28 mm",
        "order": "19"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3719": {
    "type": "formLabel",
    "label": "Loft Access Requirements",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "20",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null
  },
  "3720": {
    "type": "radioGroup",
    "label": "Crawlers",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "21",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null,
    "child": [
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "No",
        "order": "22"
      },
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "Yes",
        "order": "23"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3723": {
    "type": "radioGroup",
    "label": "Cavity Ladders for Loft",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "24",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null,
    "child": [
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "No",
        "order": "25"
      },
      {
        "type": "radio",
        "label": "Yes",
        "order": "26"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3726": {
    "type": "image",
    "label": "Loft Photos",
    "default_value": null,
    "order": "27",
    "required": "false",
    "security": "false",
    "option": null
  }
}
```

I am trying to Deserialize it to a list of objects of types defined in this class:

```
public class DBFormField
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string default_value { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string required { get; set; }
    public DBFormFieldOption option = new DBFormFieldOption();
    public List<DBFormFieldChild> child = new List<DBFormFieldChild>();
}

public class DBFormFieldOption
{
    public List<DBFormFieldGrid> grid_rows = new List<DBFormFieldGrid>();
    public List<DBFormFieldGrid> grid_columns = new List<DBFormFieldGrid>();
    public string label1 { get; set; }
    public string label2 { get; set; }
    public string result_label { get; set; }
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public List<string> rows = new List<string>();
    public string tab_id { get; set; }
}

public class DBFormFieldChild
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
}

public class DBFormFieldGrid
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried a few strategies to do this. The latest, I was trying this [http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/CustomCreationConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_CustomCreationConverter_1.htm)

For example:

```
List<DBFormField> parsedFields = new List<DBFormField>();
parsedFields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DBFormField>>(someFormObj.form_fields.ToString, new FormConverter());  // ToString???
```

...
   Public Class FormConverter
        Inherits Converters.CustomCreationConverter(Of DBFormField)

```
    Public Overrides Function Create(objectType As Type) As DBFormField
        Return New DBFormField()
    End Function
End Class
```

I suspect putting .ToString on the end of the JObject is not good enough for the DeserializeObject method? See comment above. But this code throws the error...

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RSAP.DBFormField]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.

I haven't tried serialising the JObject to a JSON string- this seems daft considering we have already parsed the JSON into a Jobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got single object in json and you try to deserialize it to list of objects - that can not be done.

Solutions:

1. You can wrap json object in array by adding `[` and `]` around object
2. You can deserialize to single object (not list):

   `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBFormField>(someFormObj.form_fields.ToString(), new FormConverter());`
3. You can deserialize single object and add it to list:

   `List<DBFormField> parsedFields = new List<DBFormField>();
   parsedField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DBFormField>someFormObj.form_fields.ToString(), new FormConverter());
   parsedFields.Add(parsedField);`

Comment: For some reason I can't work out, when you do the deserializeobject the object is empty (example 3), whether using the FormConverter or not. I will try testing with some more simple JSON strings to see if they parse ok.

Comment: As you have pointed out [link] Novakov (http://stackoverflow.com/users/995351/novakov) this cannot be done.
I have got round the problem by sending a more complete JSON string to parse.